# Постройка архетектуры десктоп приложения

Tags: python, pyqt5, flask, multiprocessing

Я хочу сделать desktop приложение, оно открывает локальный html файл, в котором через js подгружается весь контент, сам контент должен подгружаться с локального сервера, который должен запускаться вместе с программой. Сервер написан на flask, приложение на pyqt5, как сделать так, чтобы они запускались и закрывались вместе, чтобы случайно не открывались несколько копий локального сервака?

В потоках их запускать не вариант, т.к. вместе flask и pyqt5 отказываются работать, а через subprocess не понятно каким образом убивать flask приложение после закрытия основной программы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%5Bpyqt%5D+or+%5Bpyqt4%5D+or+%5Bpyqt5%5D+or+%5Bpyqt6%5D+or+%5Bpyside2%5D+%29+and+%5Bflask%5D